# Cant connect to Sentinel with redis-cli on UbuntuBash

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, redis-sentinel

I have installed Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10 PC.
After that installed Redis using `apt-get install` command
I could connect to redis using `redis-cli` command the info showed details

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.4
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a44a05d76f06a5d9
redis_mode:standalone
```

After that I created a replica I could connect to that also

Post that I started the Sentinel using the default configuration file that get installed from `/etc/redis/` folder.

The command I used to start redis is `sudo redis-server /etc/redis/sentinel1.conf --sentinel`

But if I try to connect using `redis-cli -p 26379` command I get this error

```
laptop:~$ redis-cli -p 26379
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:26379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

I checked the sentinel.conf file there the port specified is 26379

I even tried starting sentinel with `redis-sentinel /path/to/sentinel.conf`
But same error.

The same setup works fine on Ubuntu running on Virtual Machine

**Edit**

I am running Ubuntu on WIndows 10 Bash
So the `netstat -tunlpa` command shows this

```
vipresh@VIPRESHJH:/etc/redis$ sudo netstat -tunlpa
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

And the `ps aux| grep redis` command output is this

```
vipresh@VIPRESHJH:/etc/redis$ ps aux| grep redis
redis       24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ssl   2432   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ssl   2432   0:00 redis-server *:26379
vipresh     61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2432   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

It shows Sentinel is running on Port 26379

Comment: Why a vote for close??

Answer (score 0):

Check if the service is listening

```
# netstat -tunlpa | grep redis
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379        0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      xxxx
0/redis-server
```

Comment: @Vijay I am running Ubuntu on WIndows 10 Bash
So the netstat -tunlpa  command shows this

`
vipresh@VIPRESHJH:/etc/redis$ ps aux| grep redis
redis       24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ssl   2432   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ssl   2432   0:00 redis-server *:26379
vipresh     61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2432   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
`
It shows Sentinel is running on Port 26379

Comment: Tried your same exact steps on Ubuntu 16.04.1  and works as expected. But I am not sure how this is behaving differently on windows.

~# netstat -tunlpa |grep redis
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:26379           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3826/redis-server *
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3683/redis-server 1

# redis-cli -p 26379
127.0.0.1:26379> 

I suspect something with the bind address. Give a try with the IP ( -h)